# Converting xml string as parameter to class using streamReader equivalent

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader

I would like to use the equivalent of StreamReader to read/serialize xml (not retrieved from a file but passed as parameter in a string).

Here is my class:

```
public class FH
    {
        public FH();

        public bool AllowD { get; set; }
        public string C_ID { get; set; }
        public string CS_ID { get; set; }
        public FileType FT { get; set; }
        public int G_CK { get; set; }
        public string G_ID { get; set; }
        public bool IsR { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(-1)]
        public int S_CK { get; set; }
        public string S_ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my method:

```
   public static FH SerializeXMLString (string xmlstring)
            {

            string path = xmlstring;
        FH xmloutput = null;


                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FH));


                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);


                    xmloutput = (FH)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Close();

                    return xmloutput ;
            }
```

The xml (string) is as:

```
<FH>
  <G_ID>XRY</G_ID>
  <G_CK>8</G_CK>
  <CS_ID>RR03</CS_ID>
  <C_ID>YX</CI_ID>
  <AllowD>false</AllowD>
  <S_ID>1888655</S_ID>
  <S_CK>25650</S_CK>
  <FT>
    <ID>55</ID>
    <Name>MI</Name>
    <Purp>Change</Purp>
  </FT>
  <IsR>true</IsR>
</FH>
```

I realize that StreamReader is to be used for reading files and expects a path but was wondering if there was an equivalent that I could use to take my xmlstring and convert to my class (FH) prior to returning.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean "prior to returning"?

Comment: In my method (SerializeXMLString), I need to convert the xmlstring to my class (FH). This will need to be done before the method returns the FH.

Comment: and whats is your problem? in this part? xmloutput = (FH)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    reader.Close();

                    return xmloutput ;

Comment: Use StringReader(string) instead of StreamReader(filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType(TypeName = "FH")]
public class FH
{
    public string G_ID{ get; set; }
    public string G_CK{ get; set; }
    public string CS_ID{ get; set; }
    public string C_ID{ get; set; }
    public bool AllowD{ get; set; }
    public string S_ID{ get; set; }
    public string S_CK{ get; set; }
    public FT FT { get; set; }
    public bool IsR{ get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class FT
{
    public string ID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Purp{ get; set; }
}
```

First of all you should use generic methods. What will you do when deserialize a xml to another class ? You can take a look this example.

```
var response = XmlSampleHelper.SerializeXMLString<FH>(xmlstring, null);
```

And generic SerializeXMLString method,

```
    public static T SerializeXMLString<T>(string xmlstring, string schemaPath)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlstring);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(schemaPath))
            ValidateXmlDocument(reader, schemaPath);

        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlstring));
    }
```

Hope this helps.